# How to use the new Grant access in DBT for GROUPS

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

how do we specify if granting an access in DBT are for groups and per user?

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
models:
my_schema:
  schema: my_schema
  grant:
    select:
      - group: my_group
```

Comment: It seems that granting to groups is not implemented. I tested it and at the moment, the code to check grants on tables only checks user grants, and would not even detect group grants.

Answer (score 0):

As of `dbt=1.4.5`, the following works (tested only in Redshift):

```yaml
select:
  - "GROUP my_group"
```